Polars: use value from column as column name in when then expression
In a polars dataframe I have a column that contains the names of other columns (column "id_column_name"). I want to use those names in a when-then expression with pl.col() to create a new column ("id") which gets its values out of these other columns ("id_column1", "id_column2"). Every row can gets its value from another column in the df.
# initial df
df = pl.DataFrame({
        'id_column1': [123, 456],
        'id_column2': ['abc', 'def'],
        'id_column_name': ['id_column1', 'id_column2']
})

# required output df
df_out = pl.DataFrame({
    'id_column1': [123, 456],
    'id_column2': ['abc', 'def'],
    'id_column_name': ['id_column1', 'id_column2'],
    'id': ['123', 'def'] 
})

# one of the trings I tried
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col('id_column_name').is_not_null())
    .then(pl.col(pl.col('id_column_name')))
    .otherwise(None)
    .cast(pl.String)
    .alias('id')
)


This leads to the error: Expected str or DataType, got 'Expr'.

Using str() or .str to create the expression into a regular string lead to other errors:

Expected str or DataType, got 'ExprStringNameSpace'.

This cant be that hard, can it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79077774/

This question is similar to: Nested polars.col(). If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


pl.Series.unique() to get all possible values of id_column_name column.
pl.when() to create conditional results.
pl.coalesce() to fill the final result with first non-empty value.

df.with_columns(
    id = pl.coalesce(
        pl.when(pl.col.id_column_name == col).then(pl.col(col))
        for col in df.schema if col not in ("id_column_name")
        # or this if amount of columns is large
        # for col in df["id_column_name"].unique()
    )
)

shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬─────┐
│ id_column1 ┆ id_column2 ┆ id_column_name ┆ id  │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---            ┆ --- │
│ i64        ┆ str        ┆ str            ┆ str │
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════════╪═════╡
│ 123        ┆ abc        ┆ id_column1     ┆ 123 │
│ 456        ┆ def        ┆ id_column2     ┆ def │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴─────┘


Getting the column names through df["id_column_name"].unique() can be a very expensive step. That potentially has to look through hundreds of millions of values to find... two unique values.

My understanding of columnar storage (arrow format) was that it shouldn't be very expensive if cardinality is not high. But you probably know better as core dev.
I'll add some options to the answer.
